# Getting an Exception on endless Object generation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating an endless runner, and generating  obstacles randomly for my game.What happens is i am getting following exception but that is not affects to play the game that much, will it be a problem at the end, if i'm implementing it to android platform?

Exception:

> ArgumentException: RandomRangeInt can only be called from the main
>   thread.
>       Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
>       Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.
>       UnityEngine.Random.Range (Int32 min, Int32 max) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineRandomBindings.gen.cs:30)
>       wall..ctor ()

code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class wall : MonoBehaviour {
public Vector3 spawnPoint;
private Transform camPos;
private int ranXpos = Random.Range(-5,6);

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () { 
      transform.position= new Vector3(ranXpos,spawnPoint.y,spawnPoint.z);
      camPos = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
      transform.position += Vector3.back;
      if(transform.position.z< camPos.position.z)
      {
          Destroy(gameObject);
      }
    }
}
```

How to get away from this exception?

Comment: You should use UnityEngine.Random.Range(int max, int min) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Firstly You cannot go further if you getting an exception,though it works fine.
- Secondly You can't use `Random.Range` as an initializer for a static
  variable. Add an `Awake` or `Start` method and initialize 
  there.By looking at you code, what you can do is split your
  `Random.Range` declaration as follows

  ```
      public class wall : MonoBehaviour {
      public Vector3 spawnPoint;
      private Transform camPos;
      private int ranXpos ;   //MODIFICATION
          // Use this for initialization
          void Start () {
           ranXpos = Random.Range(-5,6);  //MODIFICATION  
            transform.position= new Vector3(ranXpos,spawnPoint.y,spawnPoint.z);   
            camPos = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<Transform>();
          }   
          // Update is called once per frame
          void Update () {
            transform.position += Vector3.back;
            if(transform.position.z< camPos.position.z)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
          }
      }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation.

Comment: Actually, the member "ranXpos" is not static. Initializing it with an engine call result can still be problematic, because engine calls are only allowed in the main Unity thread. Unity however may dispatch asset loading into background threads, and asset loading will also have to instantiate MonoBehaviours, which will then call the engine. That's why there are Awake() and Start() methods. They are guarenteed to be called in the main Unity thread, allowing you to safely initialize your members with Random and other engine api.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use,

```
private int ranXpos = Random.Range(-5, 6);
```

inside `start()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer